# How to compress a Video file(.wmv,.avi,.flv) without affecting its video quality

Tags: c#-2.0

I am doing a process in which i compress files of all types,for compression/decompression i used GZipStream class ,i easily compress all types of files but when it comes to a video file the compressed filesize is more than the original filesize
so the purpose of compressing gets spoiled.how to compress a video file without losing the
quality of the video successfully.

ok i accept this.but what about the winrar

Comment: +1 to counter downvote. the guys below are right.. the downvoter probably expected you to know this, but... we're all here to learn.

Comment: "What about: WinRar. Look it's simple - if you have a piece of lead - no matter how hard you hit it with the hammer it will change the shape but will not weight less - the only way to make it smaller is to cut a piece but then it's not the same piece of lead anymore. Say you have not a video, but GIF file (compressed) Compressing it further with ZIP, BZIP2, WINRAR will (maybe give) you 1% yeild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the formats are already compressed. Just by converting from format to format you most likely will kill the quality without gaining much in limiting the size

Answer (score 1):

Your video files are already compressed, which is why compressing them again increases their size.

You cannot compress them further without losing quality.